# Function seems to return undefined even though within the function, the variable returned has a value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a function to return a boolean value to that which called it and no matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work (this is running in a script that is required by a main script in another file), here is my current code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});

async function checkschema(name) {
    try {
        client.connect()
        client.query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '${name}');`, (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let result = JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]["exists"])
            console.log("result is: "+result) // logs "result is: true/false"
            client.end()
            return result
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("error: "+JSON.stringify(err))
    }
}

module.exports.getdata = (serverid, userid) => {
    checkschema(serverid).then((result) => {
        console.log("result 2 is: "+result) // logs "result 2 is: Undefined"
        return result;
    })
}
```

What confuses me is when I run something like this:

```js
async function check() {
    let result = true
    console.log("result 1 is: "+result) // result is: true
    return result

}

check().then((result) => {
    console.log("result 2 is: "+result) // result is: true
})
```

everything works.

Comment: You'll want to use the promise-based version of [`client.query()`](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) so you can return that promise from `checkschema`. Right now, your function returns nothing

Comment: Hi @Phil Do you mean using client.query like `res = await client.query()`or  maybe something like `client.query() => Promise<Result>`?

Comment: The first one, `res = await.client.query()`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I've never tried doing something like this before or even used asynchronous functions and promises.

Comment: In modern JS, avoid using APIs that use the old-school `(err, res) => { ... }` callback. Most offer promise-based versions these days

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the info, though how would I extract and return the data? I'm new to promises and have hardly any clue on how to use them

Comment: Your code should pretty much look the same except you won't have it within the `(err, res)` callback